# XMPPFramework not found

Tags: ios, xcode7, xmppframework

So i'm making a chat kind of app using xmppframework by Robbie Hanson. I can use the framework successfully as it works on Simulator. But as soon as i try to build it on a device i get `-ld:Framework not found XMPPFramework`. I have tried:
1.Enabling bitcode.
2.Removing and re adding architectures. 
3.Changing the framework search paths also library search paths. 
4.Adding `$(OTHER_LDFLAGS)` linker flags 
5.Setting build active architecture to both yes and no.

Also,
I'm getting errors for both arm64 and armv7s. I'm getting another error that can't find input directory(no such file or directory found).
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i figured it out. It was an issue of importing framework. I was importing version 3.7.2 through a podspec file. After i reverted it back to 3.6.6 its working fine.